# Node.JS webserver with CGI support (Open Source)

Tags: node.js, cgi, webserver

Is there an open source Node.JS webserver available yet that has CGI support?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [node-cgi](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-cgi) module (found through npm registry) which looks to be actively maintained.

Comment: I'm afraid it may not be so actively maintained anymore ;)

Comment: @Tom **Why?** Maybe not by the same author, but by other people. **That's open-source.**

Comment: Judging by the network graph on Github, https://github.com/pludov/node-cgi is the most recently updated fork as of July 2019. Last updated early 2018.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a CGI module to run node.js under webservers like Apache or IIS then [cgi-node](http://www.cgi-node.org/) will allow you to do just that.

Apache example: you can add a .htaccess file within your web folder to point all *.jscirpt files to be executed using Node.js through the cgi-node module. Something like this:

```
Action cgi-node /cgi-bin/cgi-node.js 
AddHandler cgi-node .jscript
```

Also including the cgi-node.js script found on the [cgi-node.org](http://www.cgi-node.org/) website within the cgi-bin folder.

CGI-Node allows Node.js to behaves exactly like PHP when running under a webserver.

Documentations and tutorials available on the site: [cgi-node.org](http://www.cgi-node.org/)

Comment: Interesting! How's the performance like? How much of a bottleneck is this compared to running node directly?

Comment: Is there any tutorial for cgi-node? I need one because I have never used any cgi extension other than PHP

Comment: @uei-richo Is this ready for production use or tested scalably?